# Want to Add product in Guest User Cart through API for Magento App

Tags: magento-1.8, shopping-cart, guest-checkout

I want to add product in a shopping cart for guest user and if product is out of stock then it should show message that product is out of stock otherwise add product in the cart. I am using Magento API . Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. Get the cart-id from the query string and pass it  in $_REQUEST[‘cart_id’]

Use this code to add product in a cart for guest user

try {

```
// if we already have cartid then pass otherwise create new cart with the help of  else part        

if(isset($_REQUEST['cart_id'])) {

      $cart_id = $_REQUEST['cart_id'];

} else {

    $cart_id = $client->call( $sessionId, 'cart.create', array( $storeId ) );

}



$product_id = $_REQUEST['product_id'];

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

$qty = $_REQUEST['qty'];



if (isset($_REQUEST['opt_value'])) {

      $options=$_REQUEST['opt_value'];  

                      $options_arr = array();

      foreach($options as $attribute_code => $opt) {

        $attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')

        ->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $attribute_code);

        $options_arr[$attributeId]= $opt;

         }

         $arrProducts = array(array(

            "product_id" => $product_id,

            "qty" => $qty,

            "super_attribute" => $options_arr

        ));

         } else {

          $arrProducts = array(array(

                "product_id" => $product_id,

             "qty" => $qty

        ));

        }   

      $data=array();

              $stockProduct = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')

               ->loadByProduct($product);

      $productActualQty = $stockProduct->getQty();

       $data['cart_total'] = getCartItemcount();

      if($product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock())

    {

         $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

         $_item = $quote ? $quote->getItemByProduct($product) : false;

             $cartItemQty = $_item ? $_item->getQty() : 0;

             $remaningQty=$productActualQty - $cartItemQty;

              if($remaningQty > 0 )

                { 

                     $resultCartProductAdd =        $client->call($sessionId,"cart_product.add",array($cart_id,$arrProducts));





        $data['cart_id'] = $cart_id;

        $data['status'] = 'SUCCESS';

        echo json_encode($data);



        }

        else

              {

             $data['status']='Out Of stock';    

              echo json_encode($data); 



               }

        }

         else {

             $data['status']='Out Of stock';

             echo json_encode($data);

            }



    }

    catch(Exception $ex) {

        echo $ex->getMessage();

        $data=array();

        $data['status']='FAILED';

        echo json_encode($data);



    }
```

Make sure your cart is active or otherwise set your cart active and then proceed.